# How to perform integration by parts on a term containing the gradient of a gradient?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, finite-element-method

I have $u\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and the term $\epsilon = (\nabla u)^\top + \nabla u$.

Since $\nabla u = \begin{pmatrix}
            \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial z} \\
            \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial z} \\
            \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix}$, I have summarized $\epsilon$ to be $\epsilon=\begin{pmatrix}
            \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x} \\
            \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial y} \\
            \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial z}
        \end{pmatrix}$.

With some boundary conditions of the problem I'm trying to solve I can reduce $\epsilon$ to $U = \begin{pmatrix}
            \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} &
            \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y} &
            \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial z} &
            \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial y} &
            \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x} &
            \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}
        \end{pmatrix}^\mathbf{T}$.

Now I have the term $\int_\Omega \nabla (eU) \cdot v \text{ d}x$ with $e\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 6}, v\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$. To eliminate the second order derivatives of $u$ I want to integrate it by parts.

My solution to this looks like this: $eU\cdot v - 
    \int_\Omega e U \cdot \nabla v \text{ d}x$.

Now I have two questions:

1. Is the way of summarizing the terms in $\epsilon$ correct in the first place?
2. Is my integration by parts correct? I feel unsure about it because I've somehow expected both terms to stay in integrals but maybe changing the integration boundaries to $\partial\Omega$.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: $\epsilon U$ is a vector. Is the first factor in the integrand supposed  to be a divergence? If so, try Green's identity

Comment: This is already the result of Green's 2nd identity.
Initially I had the term
$\int_\Omega  (\nabla \cdot (e U)) \cdot v\text{ d}x$,
applied the divergence theorem to get
$\int_{\partial \Omega } ((e U) \cdot \mathbf{n}) \cdot v\text{ d}s$
and then Green's 2nd identity to get
$ \int_{\Omega } \nabla (eU) \cdot v \text{ d}x + \int_{\Omega } e U \cdot \nabla v \text{ d}x$.

Comment: There shouldn't be any functions outside of integrals in your answer. Everything should either be an integral over $\Omega$ or an integral over $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: What is $U$ in $\int_\Omega \nabla (eU) \cdot v \text{ d}x$?

Comment: @Korf I'm sorry, it was really late last night. I've corrected my post. $U$ is the reduced version of $\epsilon$, i.e. the $6\times 1$ vector containing the selection of derivatives.